# Still getting ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage after using --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines

This has been killing me for the last couple of days. I have read everything I can find on this error and have done what xamarin says but it still doesn't work.

I can't get my builds to get through azure pipeline xamarin.ios build and deploy to apple.

When I build locally I get messages like

```
MTOUCH : warning MT1502: One or more reference(s) to type 'UIKit.UIWebView' already exists inside 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' before linking
```

with a companion message that says no references after linking
when I use --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView with the optimize arg.

When I build on azure in my pipeline, I only see the MT1502 but nothing saying anything after linking. The build gets submitted to Apple and fails because of the ITMS message.

I don't know what to do. I am using the latest macOS vm image, mono 6.8.0.123, xamarin.ios 13.16.0.13, xcode 11.4.1. The pipeline worked fine before April 30 deadline, now no matter what, I can't get the linker to strip UIWebView.

Let me know what other info would be helpful. I am completely stuck at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: [https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9823](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9823)

Comment: @VahidShir Thanks, I've read that thread a number of times and have done everything in it with no success.

Comment: Yes, other people have same issue too. That's why I shared that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got my build to pass Apple's inspection.

What ended up working for me was building locally and packaging the ipa file. On my mac I then changed the ipa extension to zip and unzipped it. I used terminal to go to the YOURAPPNAME.app "folder" and used `grep -r UIWebView .` to search for references. Don't forget the `.` so it searches the current directory. I missed that at first and got some message that grep was listening on stdin.

For me that resulted in a line like this:
`Binary file ./Frameworks/PersonalizedAdConsent.framework/PersonalizedAdConsent matches`

Now, the important thing to note is the linker never warned about this, so I was completely unaware of it. In my case it was part of Firebase/Admob. I was only one release behind and updating to the latest fixed my problem.

I still am using `--optimize=force-rejected-types-removal --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView -warnaserror:1503` as my mtouch args. But builds now get through.

I hope this helps point you guys in the right direction, I've spent the last 3 days just trying to get builds to upload reading every post I could find on the web on this problem.

Comment: I know we're not meant to say 'Thanks' in SO, but THANKS anyway!  This solved what I was believing was an insurmountable problem allowed me to get a project to beta testing, rather than needing the ugly 'we have to wait for an update' excuse.  Really appreciate you posting!  (And yes, this message IS too emotive and verbose.)

Comment: [This page from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/13/13.16#help-with-uiwebview-deprecation) has more details.  This method will let you publish but the resulting app may crash if a library actively uses `UIWebView`.

Comment: In my case the method found the UIWebView at MaterialComponents.framework/MaterialComponents. I installed last version "Xamarin.iOS.MaterialComponents" and pass Apple's inspection. Also MaterialComponents wasn't installed before at all in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !! I had to update the way how nugets are included to the iOS project .csproj file. The problem was that linker despite the --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal flag was not removing the UIWebView component form Xamarin.Forms 4.6 probably because it did not see it.

My project was created over two years ago and I was still using the packages.config file. After the update the flag started to work and grep query returned 0 :). The best way is to compare the old .csproj file with freshly created iOS project .csproj file and see how VS is referencing nugets.